# How do I get Athena software to print barcodes?

Tags: barcode

I'm using a library software called Athena. For some strange reason, it isn't printing barcodes anymore. All it's doing is printing the actual numbers where the barcode is supposed to be. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Update - Now i've got a font, but I cant figure out where in the heck you change the font that Athena uses.

Software name : Athena
Purpose : Library catalogging software
Producer : Sagebrush Corporation

Comment: There is nowhere near enough detail, in present form, to answer this question.

Comment: Ah, I think the tech guy found it. Apparantly, there's a special font required in order to print Barcodes. When the computer went down for maintenance, there was a purge and reinstallation of software, but the font that the Athena library software requires does not come pre-packaged. Hewitt Packard offers to sell the font for 85 dollars, but the tech guy found an open-source one for free. Suprising.

Answer (score 1):

The Athena Workstation Manager provides the option to install these fonts.
Run wma.exe from the Athena folder.
Enter the administrative password.
Choose Install fonts for barcode.

Answer (score 1):

I installed barcode code to `:my Computer-Windows-Fonts` or just copy and past barcode code `c39h24l4_0`, `c39m24dm_0` and `c39m24l4_0`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it use a specific font in order to print the barcodes? If so, do you have the font? Have you changed the system configuration, reinstalled software etc. recently?

Comment: Yeah, the tech guy just asked that as well, lol. Thank you though!